# Putting figures in MacTex

Tags: graphics, mactex

I don't know why but I'm not being able to put an image in my Latex file. I'm using MacTex and saving the code in .tex extension. Also I put the image in the same place I'm saving the file/code. Can someone please help me? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{STUFF}
\subsection{FiguresTest}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{width=\linewidth}{iplace.jpg}
  \caption{A place.}
  \label{fig:place1}
\end{figure}
The figure\ref{fig:place1} shows a place.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to include a figure

```
\includegraphics{width=\linewidth}
```

with name `width=\linewidth` You *must* have had errors in the log about that.

the options go in square brackets

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{iplace.jpg}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm printing the image. However when I write  "The figure\ref{fig:place1} shows a place." It doesn't print the result properly. What appears is: "The figure ?? shows a place.

Comment: @GrangerObliviate latex it twice to resolve cross references

Comment: Problem solved :) Thank you very much. I only have one last question: why does the sentence "The figure 1 shows a place" appears before my image and not after the image (as I wrote in the code?)

Comment: @GrangerObliviate that is the point of the figure environment  it specifies a _float_ that latex can move around (typically to top of a page) to help with page breaking.